# Where do I change these VBA declarations in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I was handed an accounting spreadsheet to recreate because of some broken references.  I'm not really versed in Excel and am having trouble finding where certain declarations are coming from within the Excel document.  I'm sure this is extremely simple, yet I apparently can't figure it out...  In the following VBA modules within an excel document I see the following code:

```
Dim OriginalQi As Double, OriginalGOR_Initial As Double

OriginalQi = Range("Input_Qi")
OriginalGOR_Initial = Range("Input_GOR_Initial")
```

I am a programmer and understand the decelerations of the OriginalQi and OriginalGOR_Initial doubles.  What I can't seem to find within Excel is where the "Input_Qi" and "Input_GOR_Initial" strings are being declared and given values.  I'm sure there is a menu somewhere in Excel that should display these given names and the values they contain, but I cannot find it.  Can someone please point out to me where these references are stored within the Excel document.

Comment: Formulas tab, click Name Manager. They are named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory pointed out in a comment above:

Formulas tab / Name Manager

Answer (score 0):

You can't find them because they are hidden. This procedure will unhide all names in the workbook.

```
Sub Unhide_Names()
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        nm.Visible = True
    Next nm
End Sub
```

After running the code, go back to Excel and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open up Name Manager, you should see all the names now.